# Apache 2 problems accessing localhost

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2, localhost

This is my first post here and I hope I'm doing the right way.

I installed apache2 in my ubuntu 14.04 local machine for studying purposes and all my files are in my home public_html folder.

When I try to access a site like localhost/~{user}/test/index.php everything works fine, but when I try to access the same site with localhost/home/{user}/public_html/test/index.php I get the following error:

> The requested URL /home/{user}/public_html/test/index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I tried to use:

```
$echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

But it  returns /home/{user}/public_html/test.

So why can't I access the same file with both paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets' consider the second URL:

```
http://localhost**/home/user/test/index.php**
```

If you look in Apache's configuration you will notice that there is a directive called "DocumentRoot". This directive specifies where apache will map the initial "/" in the URL to.

So, let's say that the DocumentRoot is set to /var/www/htdocs. When you request the path  /home/user/test/index.php it will actially go looking for .... /var/www/htdocs/home/user/test/index.php, which I'm assuming doesn't exist. See [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#DocumentRoot)

Ok, so why does the first one work? Because of Apache's [UserDir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) module. This little module checks the "/~user/test/index.php" part of the link. The tilde (~) is what does it :).  It then maps /~user/ to /home/user/, thus Apache will look for the file at /home/user/test/index.php. Voilá.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I looked in my apache2.conf file and couldn't find any DocumentRoot directive so I added one:

>DocumentRoot /

And still I can't access the http://localhost/home/user/public_html/test/index.php

Comment: You will not be able to acces that url, unless you set the docroot to the actual root. For the love of everytjing pire, DON'T. Instead, set the document root to the home of the user. Afterwards, you'll be able to access this url: http://localhost/test/index.php

Comment: Also, there is already a documentroot somewhere in apaches config. For sure. Apache also supports includes in its config file. Check those files too. You might try a file that includes vjost in its name. Also please check apache's configuration documentation for your particular linux distro. One last thing: after you modify apache config, you must tell it reload it. Try restarting apache for now. Don't freak out if it doesn't restart, instead. Heck the error log?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. apache has been started. i stop apache and start nginx :

```
sudo service apache2 stop

sudo service nginx start
```